# Проблема вывода при использовании \033[1m и метода .format

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

При совместном использовании экранированной последовательности   \033[1m и метода .format слетает форматирование следующего за ним элемента ( в данном случае отступ).

Нормальные отступы без \033[1m:

```
print("{0:3} {1:3} {2:3} {3:3} {4:3} {5:3} {6:3}".format("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Слетевший отступ у элемента 6 при использовании \033[1m:

```
print("{0:3} {1:3} {2:3} {3:3} {4:3} {5:3} {6:3}".format("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "\033[5m5\033[25m", "6"))
```

Как исправить отображения форматирования и жирного текста?

Comment: А вы сами эти символы печатаете, то есть вы точно знаете заранее, где они будут, или вы получаете откуда-то такие строки в готовом виде и не можете контролировать этот процесс?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы сами управляете какие поля должны быть `bold`, а какие нет, то можно сделать, например, так:

```
BOLD_ON = "\033[1m"
BOLD_OFF = "\033[0m"

def string_format(string, width=3, bold=False):
    return f"{BOLD_ON if bold else ''}{string:{width}}{BOLD_OFF if bold else ''}"

def print_format(data, width=3):
    result = []
    for item in data:
        if isinstance(item, tuple):
            val, bold = item
            result.append(string_format(val, width, bold))
        else:
            result.append(string_format(item, width))
    print(''.join(result))
                  
print_format(("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", ("5", True), "6"), 3)
```

Можно и по-другому сделать, главное обговорить самому с собой - в каком формате должны быть данные и как помечать, где должны быть спецсимволы.